# Delete partition and restore to mac without bootcamp

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, partition

I am looking to restore my hard drive to just mac fully. I installed windows using bootcamp but in trying to remove windows as it was faulty, I accidentally removed bootcamp assistant from my mac.

I would like to delete `disk0s3` and restore it to be part of my main `Macintosh HD` which contains my mac OS install. However, I am not sure how this is organised as not sure what container disk1 is. Any advice on how I can clean this up to just have 'Macintosh HD' using the full space available? The format of `Macintosh HD` is APFS (encrypted). Should I just erase `disk0s3` and give it the same format? If so, what name should I give it?

[image]

I plan to update my mac software and recover bootcamp assistant that way hopefully to reinstall windows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To convert a Microsoft partition to free space requires a single command. For example, `disk0s3` is a Microsoft partition. To convert to free space, you would need to enter the following command.

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3
```

Free space can be added to a container, if the free space reside immediately after the container. In your case, if you converted `disk0s3` to free space, then you probably would be able add this free space to `disk0s2`, by entering the command given below.

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```